# Document Information Panel contacted a data source but failed to receive data. The form will load without the requested data

Tags: document-library, lookup-column

> The query cannot be run for the following DataObject:
>   list_48985ACC-FDDD-4732-AA48-078CFE123F35 Document Information Panel
>   cannot run the specified query. The SOAP response indicates that an
>   error occurred on the server:
>
> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>   
>       List does not exist.
>
> ```
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
> </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail>
> ```
>
> {2065aaed-3d74-4c04-a0db-8b155a5a3099}
>
> This is the error details for sharePoint 2007: The query cannot be run
>   for the following DataObject:
>   list_48985ACC-FDDD-4732-AA48-078CFE123F35 Document Information Panel
>   cannot run the specified query. The SOAP response indicates that an
>   error occurred on the server:
>
> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>   
>       List does not exist.
>
> ```
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
> </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail>
> ```
>
> {2065aaed-3d74-4c04-a0db-8b155a5a3099}

I am trying to create a new document in document library and it throws me this error.
I find that it is an issue with the Lookup  column (Doc Types) which is required type and it is not able to fetch the data from the lookup lists.

This error occurs in existing doc library which have around 2000 documents i dont know what it triggers this error. I don't want to loose the doc types(look up value from look up lists) associated with the existing solution. If i removed and re add the columns it works fine but i loose all the old doc types associated with it.

I had tried [this blog steps](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.blogspot.com/2010/01/problem-with-document-information-panel.html) but no luck.
I am getting error when i try to add the {} around the list Guid.

> **Error** : Propery value is not Valid  **Details** : Cannot change
>   the lookup list of the lookup field.

please let me know if you have any other options

Answer (score 1):

I have created another site and migrated the data using the Docave Backup and Restore tool. 
New site is working fine, there is no error for DIP.